# Detect mobile version in asp.net webform - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I am trying to redirect users of different mobile phones & tables users to mobile version of a website but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

I am using following code

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpBrowserCapabilities hbc = Request.Browser;
    if (((HttpCapabilitiesBase)hbc).IsMobileDevice)
    {
        Response.Write("You are browsing from a mobile device");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("No mobile device");
    }
}
}
```

I have also seen example where Regex is being used may be to cover wide range of devices. Please suggest what is recommended & what works.

```
String u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
     bool mobileUser = false;

                Regex b = new Regex("android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                Regex v = new Regex("1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                if (u.Length > 4)
                {
                    if (b.IsMatch(u) | v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))
                    {
                        mobileUser = true;
                    }
                }

                if (mobileUser) //mobile user!!
                {
                    mobileSiteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MobileSiteURL"];

                    Response.Redirect(mobileSiteUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                 }
```

Your expert view is required as this is my first mobile app

Comment: I'm interested in the solution you found here.  Was one of these answers helpful?

Comment: Yes, I have market correct answer for this only problem may me that you may need to update device list solution when every new device list is updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/  provide the regular expression which is quiet updated and I am using in my current project , working good. The way I have implemented is I have added HTTP Module and trap the request in BeginRequest itself . it helps me to have a single place code and can easily be part of project with update with no need to compile the whole project in case we have got the new added device in regular expression

Answer (score 1):

two recommendations for mobile detection

[51degree](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) and [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)

updated

[51degree implemention](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/releases/view/99365) and [wurfl impelemtation](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotnet_index.php)

Comment: I have (a little) experience with 51degree.  I believe that requires a server install as a plugin into IIS (if I am not mistaken).  You can accomplish this via javascript as well.  Using media queries with CSS you create dynamic sites without the need to create a different site for mobile devices.  I believe this is the new standard. (Im a .net guy so ui standards are not my forte)

Comment: @KennethGarza, Agree with you but one need to be really good with Responsive design to support mobile devices... I am more of a .Net Developer...

Comment: i understand.  Where I work we have droves of ui guys telling me how awesome this is.  My eyes glaze over and think about developing a m.whatever.com site and life would be simpler.

Comment: @ShafqatMasood I didnt know that wurlf didnt require a server install.  Never used it so I cant speak to it, but if this works without a server install that would be pretty cool.

Comment: To enable WURFL on your application you need to download the WURFL binaries and data... here is [getting started for dotnet](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotnet_index.php) article for wurfl